# I am having trouble with this error (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'resize'

Tags: python, opencv

```
line 37, in <module> curImg = cv2.resize(curImg,(32,32)) cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.1) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-6u w63ony\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\resize.cpp:4051: error: (-215:Assertion failed ) !ssize.empty() in function 'cv::resize'
```

[image]

Comment: Please add your code itself inside your question inside block quotes like `````` and provide an explanation of what the code is supposed to do. Look at [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What library are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that that OpenCV did not find a file where you told it to look. In Python, the return value of imread is None when it cannot find the file. To help debug, you could add an extra if statement:

```
if curImg is None:
    print('no image found: ', path + '/' + str(x) + "/" + y)
else:
    curImg = cv2.resize(curImg, (32,32))
    images.append(curImg)
    classNo.append(x)
```

Comment: if curImg == 0:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous.
 Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: Oops. I should have tested before I posted. Return value is None when imread cannot find the file. Answer is now updated